# Can Bash scripts (or their children) be given special IDs that could be used to test against?

Tags: shell-script

Is there something I could add to a Bash script to always assert correctly if it's running so a it can not be executed simultaneously with itself or some other script.

I was thinking like they way capture groups can be named in regex or the `name` or `id` keyword in HAProxy. A variable the could be set and unset at the end but, or a reliable version of this that is unset automatically in case of exiting prematurely (thus never unsetting this random variable blocking itself to run later)

Is there?

Comment: Typically some form of [file locking](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/flock.1.html) is used to prevent simultaneous execution.

Comment: The 'special ID' can be the process id (and/or the parent process id).